# rails app using resque .i am always getting SystemExit Error exit error as falied jobs when viewing in resque web interface.how to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

i have class Compile in /lib whose method i run in the resque class in app/workers

the resque class is this

```
         $:.unshift(Rails.root.join("lib"))
         require "Compile.rb"
         class CC
              @queue= :results_queue
              def self.perform(pid,x,fn,lang)
                      Dir.chdir(Rails.root.join("lib"));
                      tcid=fn[2..3];
                      fe=(Rails.root.join('sub',x)).to_s;
                      ipf=(Rails.root.join('io',pid,fn));
                      utf=(Rails.root.join('io',pid,"ans"+tcid.to_s));
                      ***res=Compile::Compile.runcode(fe.to_s,lang,1,ipf.to_s,utf.to_s);***
              end
   end
```

end

Compile.rb has class is this

module Compile
        class Compile
                def self.runcode(file,lang,tl,inpf,outf)
........

i always get failed job Exception SystemExit
error exit
but when i remove the res=.. line which is between *** above there is no failed job.
can anybody help me out??

Comment: We would really need to know more about what `Compile.rb` looks like and what the code that is presumably being executed (`fe`) does in order to offer much help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it debugged.understood the problem